# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly|Custom Game| Python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, integer, type-conversion

Hey guys this a little bit of a game i'm working on. The error is, to my knowledge, is that when you first go into the bank and withdraw cash to onhand its fine, but the next time it reads onhand it shoves me |Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly| Anyway it seems once you use the onhand = int(onhand) + int(amount2) it changes the string in some why that cant be displayed in print ("~ On Hand: " + onhand) thanks guys

## Start

```
  import time
    energy = "10"
    int(energy)
    money = "500"
    onhand = "10"
    int(money)
    int(onhand)
```

## PLAYER CREATION

```
print ("Create Your Player!")
print (".......................")
name = input ("What's Your Name:") 
print ('Okay Gotcha ' + name)
time.sleep (2)
print ('')
age = input ("What's Your Age Sir?:")
print ("Okay Gotcha you're " + age)
time.sleep (2)
print ('')      
hometown = input ("Where Are You From?:")
print ("It's Nice Over In " + hometown + ' huh')
time.sleep (2)
print ('')
print ("Well im done here. Have a nice trip!")
time.sleep (5)
print ('')
#PLAYER CREATION
```

## 1ST MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU 1ST

```
count = 0
while count < 1000:
    print (' ')
    print (' ')
    print (' ')
    print ('You walk into your room what do you do?')
    print ("~~~~~~~~~energy~~| "+ energy + '|~~Name:~~|' + name)
    print ('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ 1  |  Check Bank Account     ~")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ 2  |  Go Eat At Tiffany's    ~")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ 3  |  Tour Jurrasic Park     ~")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ 4  |  Work      +$7          ~")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ 5  |  Sleep     +10 energy   ~") 
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    choice1 = input ("Enter Choice:")
```

## 1ST MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU 1ST

## BANK BANK BANK

```
if int(choice1) == 1:
    print (' ')
    print ("~~~~~~~~~energy~~| "+ energy + '|~~Name:~~|' + name)
    print ("~ First Dodo National Bank ~")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ Name: " + name)
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ Age: " + age)
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ Bank #: 12342215")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ Balance: " + money)
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ On Hand: " + onhand)
    time.sleep (3)
    print ('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
    print (' ')
    print ('1 | Deposit')
    print ('2 | Withdraw')
    print ('3 | Leave')
    choice2 = input ("Enter Choice:")
    print ('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
    if int(choice2) == 1:
        amount1 = input ('Enter Amount:')
        if int(amount1) > int(onhand):
            print ('You Dont Have That Much Money On Hand.') 
        elif int(amount1) <= int(onhand):
            money =  int(money) + int(amount1)
            count += 1
    elif int(choice2) == 2:
         amount2 = input ('Enter Amount:')
         if int(amount2) > int(money):
             print ('You Dont Have That Money In The Bank.') 
         elif int(amount2) <= int(money):
            onhand = int(onhand) + int(amount2)
            count += 1
    elif int(choice2) == 3:
        count += 1
```

## BANK BANK BANK

## Full Code

```
import time
energy = "10"
int(energy)
money = "500"
onhand = "10"
int(money)
int(onhand)
#PLAYER CREATION
print ("Create Your Player!")
print (".......................")
name = input ("What's Your Name:") 
print ('Okay Gotcha ' + name)
time.sleep (2)
print ('')
age = input ("What's Your Age Sir?:")
print ("Okay Gotcha you're " + age)
time.sleep (2)
print ('')      
hometown = input ("Where Are You From?:")
print ("It's Nice Over In " + hometown + ' huh')
time.sleep (2)
print ('')
print ("Well im done here. Have a nice trip!")
time.sleep (5)
print ('')
#PLAYER CREATION



#INTRO
print ('You Just Flew In From Your Home Town Of ' + hometown + " You're Excited About Your New Job In Jurassic Park")
time.sleep (4)
print ('')
print ('Bob: Well ' + name + ' Welcome To JURASSIC PARK!')
time.sleep (2)
print ('')
print ("Bob: So you're the new guy huh? Well I think you'll like it here.")
time.sleep (4)
print ('')
print ("Bob: Anyways your job is at the souvenir stand ")
time.sleep (3)
print ('')
print ("Bob: You can also get promoted so you won't be stuck selling rubber dinos forever don't worry")
time.sleep (3)
print (" ")
print ("Bob: ah here we are! *You arrive at a hotel inn called ~Le Dodo Pin~* Bob: Well good luck and if you")
print (" ")
time.sleep (2)
print ("get lost there are maps everywhere, if you're looking for a place to eat Tiffanys is one of the best")
print (" ")
time.sleep (2)
print ("food joints around here, anyways I have to go good luck! Don't let the dinos bite haha.")
time.sleep (4)
#INTRO

# 1ST MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU 1ST
count = 0
while count < 1000:
    print (' ')
    print (' ')
    print (' ')
    print ('You walk into your room what do you do?')
    print ("~~~~~~~~~energy~~| "+ energy + '|~~Name:~~|' + name)
    print ('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ 1  |  Check Bank Account     ~")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ 2  |  Go Eat At Tiffany's    ~")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ 3  |  Tour Jurrasic Park     ~")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ 4  |  Work      +$7          ~")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("~ 5  |  Sleep     +10 energy   ~") 
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    choice1 = input ("Enter Choice:")
# 1ST MENU MENU MENU MENU MENU 1ST


#BANK BANK BANK
    if int(choice1) == 1:
        print (' ')
        print ("~~~~~~~~~energy~~| "+ energy + '|~~Name:~~|' + name)
        print ("~ First Dodo National Bank ~")
        time.sleep (1)
        print ("~ Name: " + name)
        time.sleep (1)
        print ("~ Age: " + age)
        time.sleep (1)
        print ("~ Bank #: 12342215")
        time.sleep (1)
        print ("~ Balance: " + money)
        time.sleep (1)
        print ("~ On Hand: " + onhand)
        time.sleep (3)
        print ('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        print (' ')
        print ('1 | Deposit')
        print ('2 | Withdraw')
        print ('3 | Leave')
        choice2 = input ("Enter Choice:")
        print ('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        if int(choice2) == 1:
            amount1 = input ('Enter Amount:')
            if int(amount1) > int(onhand):
                print ('You Dont Have That Much Money On Hand.') 
            elif int(amount1) <= int(onhand):
                money =  int(money) + int(amount1)
                count += 1
        elif int(choice2) == 2:
             amount2 = input ('Enter Amount:')
             if int(amount2) > int(money):
                 print ('You Dont Have That Money In The Bank.') 
             elif int(amount2) <= int(money):
                onhand = int(onhand) + int(amount2)
                count += 1
        elif int(choice2) == 3:
            count += 1
#BANK BANK BANK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can't be done implicitly do it explicitly as such

```
print ("~ On Hand: " + str(onhand))
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument you're giving to the print, `"~ On Hand: " + onhand` is a string concatenation. Both parts must be a string in order for you to be able to join the two together. Once you've done `onhand = int(onhand) + int(amount2)` then `onhand` is an integer, not a string.

There are two main ways to do string formatting. The one I find simplest is the `.format()` method, which replaces `{}` in the string with the arguments given to `format`:

```
"~ On Hand: {}".format(onhand)
```

You can also use [% operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), such as:

```
" ~ On Hand: %s" % onhand
```

Incidentally, these:

```
int(money)
int(onhand)
```

since they're on lines by themselves, don't do anything useful.